# Put different backgrounds in a View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios6, background, xcode4.5

I am doing my first steps creating applications in iOS, so maybe I am asking a dumb question. 
In a View Controller, I put some buttons and text fields to make different actions. To improve the organization, I want to put several backgrounds with borders to delimitate the areas where the buttons and text fields are placed.
I tried putting a text label without text and color background, and move my objects over it, but I don't know why the layer is placed over the buttons and text fields. Then, I tried modifying the text label's opacity, but it's totally unsatisfactory.

```
label1.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
label1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
label1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
label1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
label1.layer.opacity = 0.1;
label1.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Can help me anyone to find a better way to do this or improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

1) you could just use a normal UIView instead of a label with no text (same difference just more correct)

2) in the story board the order in which the UI elements are on the left bar is important, it is basically the draw order of the elements, the ones at the top are drawn first, therefore things below it will be drawn over

Answer (score 0):

You can try in Interface Builder to put multiple UIImageView objects and set your backgrounds as desired from Attributes Inspector and watch out how you put your elements in your UIView. The ones below are drawn after the ones at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, ...

Make yourself familiar with the logic behind the subview hierarchy and the drawing sequence of siblings. 
In your interface builder/storyboard you could align the views as followed:

```
   UIView (the default view that is connected to the view controller's view property) 
    \--UIView   (This is a background to group UI Items as buttons or Lables
       \-- UILabel
       \-- UIButton
    \--UIView (the next background) 
       \-- UILabel
       \-- UIButton
```

When it comes to coorindates then you will notice that the coordinates of each view are relative to its subview. So the UILabel and UIButton might have the same coordinates but each of them will be located within its very subview.

Another option would be:

```
UIView (the default view that is connected to the view controller's view property) 
\--UIView (Background) 
\--UIButton
\--UILable
\--UIView (Background) 
\--UIButton
\--UILable
```

Or even

```
UIView (the default view that is connected to the view controller's view property) 
\--UIView (Background) 
\--UIView (Background) 
\--UIButton
\--UILable
\--UIButton
\--UILable
```

In that case all UI elemets share the same coordinate space. In that case you need to care for a proper layout.

This one is would not work: 
    UIView (the default view that is connected to the view controller's view property) 
    --UIButton
    --UILable
    --UIButton
    --UILable
    --UIView (Background) 
    --UIView (Background) 
Even if all coordinates etc. are identical with those of the examples above, the two background views would hide the other UI elements just because they are drawn after the others. And the last one wins the space.